# Magento 2: Add Product Attribute Filters on Magento 2 Custom Product Collection

Tags: magento2, collection, product-collection

I've a custom product collection displayed on a custom page. This part is working fine.

Now I want to add the product attribute filter on that page to provide customers to filter the products based on the product attribute, same as the category page filters (display below).

[image: category page filter options]

How it is possible in Magento 2?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: you want your created custom product attributed show in left side navigation. after category filter.?